# Saving the XMM register before function call

Tags: x86-64, intel, avx2, sse

Is it required to save/push the any XMM registers to the stack before the assembly function call?
Because am observing the crash issue in my code with release mode for 64-bit development(Using AVX2). In debug mode its working fine. I tried with saving the content of the XMM8 register and restoring it at end of function call then its working fine.

Any idea or references?

Comment: Yes, but which calling convention? Win64 or SystemV? xmm8 is caller-save in both, but I'd give you a different reference.

Comment: Am using the Std calling convention.

Comment: Well, that isn't really one of the options for 64bit code. You could just go ahead and use it, but if you call any external function it won't work.

Comment: @Falcon, harold is really asking which operating system are you using.  On x86, the calling convention is different between Windows and everyone else. I'm going to guess that you're on Windows ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, on Microsoft Windows you are required to preserve the XMM6-XMM15 registers. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx - this includes xmm8, so either preserve them, or not use them in your function.

However on Linux those are temporary registers, and therefore don't have to be preserved. See http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf page 21.

Comment: Note that the is asking if you need to preserve XMM regs before a `call foo` instruction. 
 In Windows x64 you don't, you just save some XMM6-15 regs at the start of your whole function, and keep your vars in them so they survive across a `call`.  In Linux, you normally use stack space to keep values across a `call`.  (You're correctly answering whether your function has to save/restore any of the caller's values, which implies the answer to this question but is a different way of looking at it.)