# Visual Studio and Unity Mono register clobbering

Tags: mono, 64-bit, pinvoke, cpu-registers

As per [Saving the XMM register before function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299543/saving-the-xmm-register-before-function-call), it seems that XMM6 to XMM15 need to be preserved by function calls on Windows but don't need to be preserved on Linux.

I have a native plugin, compiled by Visual Studio 2015, for use in Unity, which uses Mono. The C# code passes a delegate down to the native plugin, which receives it as a function pointer (annotated `stdcall` for the sake of 32-bit builds, although the problem I have is with 64-bit ones). So, this means the native code can call a function which is implemented by Mono.

When I do this, the Mono function seems to be clobbering XMM6 to XMM15. The code compiled by Visual Studio obviously wasn't expecting this, and proceeds to malfunction.

Any ideas for ways to solve this? Is it possible to annotate specific function pointers so that Microsoft knows they behave wrong? Are there intrinsics we can call to save and restore those registers explicitly around any calls that we know have this problem? Other ideas?

---

Edit with further discoveries:

The registers are only clobbered the first time a given C# function is called. I've traced it to the Mono AMD64 general trampoline. [This commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ce596ec25c156c754b853ea129cdb80bd6652c35) fixes the bug, but Unity uses an old version of Mono which still has it. The bug is that XMM0 to XMM7 are saved and restored using [MOVSD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html), which only saves the lower 64 bits and resets the upper 64 bits to 0, while XMM8 to XMM15 are not saved at all, which may matter if something were to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for simple cases:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

alignas(16) std::array<uint8_t, 512> regs;
_fxsave64(regs.data());
callToMonoGoesHere();
_fxrstor64(regs.data());
```

Extra steps must be taken if the function returns a floating-point value:

```
alignas(16) std::array<uint8_t, 512> before, after;
_fxsave64(before.data());
float f = callToMonoGoesHere();
_fxsave64(after.data());
memcpy(after.data() + 256, before.data() + 256, 160); //XMM6 to 15
_fxrstor64(after.data());
```